# Pandas doing concat instead of merge on doing merge operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes,df1:

```
                      name              mark
     0               Alex  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]
     1               John  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]
     2                Tom  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]
     3                Tim  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]
```

and df2:

```
           name        mark1
   0       Alex  [11.0, 0.0, 1.0]
   1       John  [12.0, 0.0, 4.0]
   2        Tom  [12.0, 0.0, 4.0]
```

and when i do :

```
merged = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on='name').fillna(0)
```

i expected to get something like this:

```
                 name              mark                   mark1
     0           Alex  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]   [11.0, 0.0, 1.0]
     1           John  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]   [12.0, 0.0, 4.0]
     2            Tom  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]   [12.0, 0.0, 4.0]
     3            Tim  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]        0
```

but i got something like this(which looks more like concat):

```
                 name              mark              mark1
     0           Alex  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]       0
     1           John  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]       0
     2            Tom  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]       0
     3            Tim  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]       0
     4           Alex          0                [11.0, 0.0, 1.0]
     5           John          0                [12.0, 0.0, 4.0]
     6            Tom           0               [12.0, 0.0, 4.0]
```

can someone please tell me what wrong am i doing?
so this is my whole code :

```
                       name              mark
     0                Alex   [Mon, 10.12, 12, 10.0, 17.0]
     1                Alex   [Wed, 10.12, 15, 10.0, 17.0]
     2                Alex   [Fri, 10.12, 7, 10.0, 17.0]
     3                Alex   [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]
     4                Alex   [Thu, 0.0, 16, 0.0, 0.0]
     5                Alex   [Sat, 0.0, 2, 0.0, 0.0]
     6                Alex   [Sun, 0.0, 12, 0.0, 0.0]
     7                John   [Fri, 10.12, 7, 10.0, 17.0]
     8                John   [Mon, 10.12, 12, 10.0, 17.0]
     9                John   [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]
    10               John   [Wed, 0.0, 15, 0.0, 0.0]
    11               John   [Thu, 0.0, 16, 0.0, 0.0]
    12               John   [Sat, 0.0, 2, 0.0, 0.0]
    13               John   [Sun, 0.0, 12, 0.0, 0.0]
    14                Tom  [Wed, 10.12, 15, 10.0, 17.0]
    15                Tom  [Mon, 10.12, 12, 10.0, 17.0]
    16                Tom   [Fri, 10.12, 7, 10.0, 17.0]
    17                Tom   [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]
    18                Tom   [Thu, 0.0, 16, 0.0, 0.0]
    19                Tom   [Sat, 0.0, 2, 0.0, 0.0]
    20                Tom   [Sun, 0.0, 12, 0.0, 0.0]
    21                Tim  [Mon, 10.12, 12, 10.0, 17.0]
    22                Tim  [Fri, 10.12, 7, 10.0, 17.0]
    23                Tim   [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]
    24                Tim   [Wed, 0.0, 15, 0.0, 0.0]
    25                Tim   [Thu, 0.0, 16, 0.0, 0.0]
    26                Tim   [Sat, 0.0, 2, 0.0, 0.0]
    27                Tim   [Sun, 0.0, 12, 0.0, 0.0]
```

and then i do :

```
df = (df.groupby(['name'])['mark'].apply(list).apply(lambda x: [list(y) for y 
                 in set([tuple(j) for j in x])]).reset_index())
```

which gives me :

```
                  name                                               mark
 0               Alex  [[Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0], [Sun, 0.0, 12, 0.0,...
 1               John  [[Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0], [Sun, 0.0, 12, 0.0,...
 2                Tom  [[Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0], [Sun, 0.0, 12, 0.0,...
 3                Tim  [[Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0], [Sun, 0.0, 12, 0.0,...
```

second dataframe is also obtained by doing something like this.(sorry for not placing the exact dataframe cuz it was kind of messy)

Comment: When you set the parameter `how` to `outer`, you are performing a full outer join. Instead you want to set it to `how = 'left'` to perform a left join. Read up on SQL joins to get more insight.

Comment: thanks @MrSoLoDoLo for commenting.I tried it but it sets all 'mark1' values for df1 equals to NaN

Comment: Check the consistency of your `name` columns. It seems there is a leading space for the names in `df2`. E.g.  `' John'`.

Comment: That is probably a typo...sorry for that

Comment: Show your full code. There is probably a bug.

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo uploaded the full code.

Comment: my bad..there was a space after each name in df2...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge left, on column 'name'

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left',on='name')

  name                     mark               mark1
0  Alex  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]   [11.0, 0.0, 1.0]
1  John  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]   [12.0, 0.0, 4.0]
2   Tom  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]   [12.0, 0.0, 4.0]
3   Tim  [Tue, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0]                NaN
```

Comment: thank for ur quick response @wwnde .I tried this but it sets all 'mark1' values to 'NaN'

Comment: please ensure column 'name' and its values are spelled in the same way in the two dataframes. Ensure there are no spaces before or after name

Comment: I believe your names are not the same in the two dataframes. You quite likely have spaces before or after. If you eliminate them, your initial solution should work as well.

Comment: my bad..there was a space after each name in df2...thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

`merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left',on='name').fillna(0)`

This is because in your merge you are performing a full outer join.

Comment: thank u for answeing ,but as mentioned above it sets all 'mark1' values to 'NaN'

Comment: It sounds like you may have changed your df2 somewhere in the process if that is happening. Please double check if df2 is okay, and let me know!

Comment: my bad..there was a space after each name in df2...thanks